# Какая сложность у сортировки подсчетом?

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, сортировка, pascalabc.net

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста какая сложность у сортировки подсчетом?
Имеется ввиду метод сортировки в котором используется вспомогательный массив, который заполняется нулями.

Сколько будет выполнено **сравнений** и **перестановок** при выполнении сортировки методом подсчёта у массива {3, 1, 6, 13, 2, 0, 8} ?

Не подскажите, куда нужно сунуть счётчики srav и perest?

```
int max = A.Max();
Array.Copy(A, B, N + 1);
Array.Resize(ref B, max + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
{
    B[i] = 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    B[A[i]]++;
}
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= max; i++)
{
    srav++;
    while (B[i] > 0)
    {
        A[j] = i;
        j++;
        B[i]--;
        perest++;
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вот как раз свеженькое https://habr.com/ru/post/689738/

Comment: @Эникейщик Большое спасибо! Как раз искал грамотно написанный код данной сортировки. Но у меня не получается посчитать количество сравнений и перестановок для массива {3, 1, 6, 13, 2, 0, 8}. Полученные мной значения не укладываются в сложность данной сортировки.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто - эта сортировка не основана на сравнениях ([Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)), так что их количество **ноль**, или O(n+к), если педантично учитывать изменение индексов в заголовках циклов. Эта сортировка не производит обменов, так что тоже ноль.

По вопросу в заголовке - сложность O(n+k), где n - количество элементов, k - диапазон значений.

Comment: @Pahomka не вставляйте код в комментарии, вставляйте в сам вопрос, его можно редактировать.

Comment: @aepot поправил